# When you write a Titanium app, is the source code visible to users?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, ria, titanium

When you write an HTML/CSS/JavaScript app for Adobe AIR, the source files sit in a directory visible to anyone who looks.

[Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop/) lets you code in JavaScript, Python, and Ruby. Is the bundling similar to AIR, with all the source exposed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Titanium FAQ](http://titaniumapp.com/faq/if-i-build-my-app-in-titanium-and-distribute-it-is-the-source-code-visible-to-the-user-in-other-words-can-the-program-be-compiled-into-a-binary-format), yes, your source code will be accessible to anyone who looks for it.

Comment: Thanks. Same source says they may be adding a way to do a binary package in the future.

Comment: We generally recommend that folks combine and obfuscate their JavaScript to make it less easy to browse on the target filesystem.  But yes, we have been looking at ways to further secure the source for the application.

Comment: To Brendan: Please tell the method to see the Source code of a "Titanium Desktop App" in Windows environment.

Answer (score 2):

As [Nosredna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61027/nosredna) added in the comment they seem to have gotten arround to that change in their newer framework versions.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work) to get some insight from an appcelerator found on how the framework works. I understand this as a compilation process that won't leave a trace of your js files in the package.