# How Titanium Appcelerator project works?

Tags: titanium

Can someone tell me how Titanium appcelrator works under the hood? How the javascript code internally is rendered on the Web View? And can we directly write HTML, CSS code in to the program? How the native functionalities of a phone are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work), where jhaynie from Titanium answers those questions. You do not write the code in Titanium, though. You write HTML, CSS and Javascript in the program of your choice, then Titanium builds it to apps for you.