# Can you develop a mobile app in appcelerator using dreamweaver?

Tags: iphone, android, appcelerator

I have been trying to make sense of some claims that Appcelerator Titanium makes. As per their site, if I know HTML and Java script, I can develop a native mobile app using their SDK. So I need someone to tell me this.

If I develop an app for calculating loan installments using a form in dream weaver that takes input (Down Payment Amount, Interest Rate, and Tenure) in text fields, apply form validation using Java script, and calculate the installment amount using Java Script, and then display the amount.

Will appcelerator turn all of this into a native app? Sounds too good to be true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium just provides a bridge so that a iphone/android app can be developed using javascript and you need not learn java or objective c for android and iphone respectively.

You may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217551/what-happens-to-javascript-code-after-app-is-compiled-using-titanium-mobile) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work) to get a picture of how titanium actually does it.

Bottom line, you cant use dreamweaver or some other "web-building" for titanium.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator can create native apps, but you need to write your app using their javascript API. Appcelerator provides the developer with a lot of javascript functions, which you then use to add views to your app (tableviews, images, text, etc).

Despite what Javanator claims, it really does turn into a native app, but no, you cannot just use any WYSIWYG html editor (i.e. Dreamweaver) you like to turn HTML into a native app.

However, Appcelerator recently bought Aptana, which is an user-friendly editor. For more information, see http://www.appcelerator.com/appcelerator-acquires-aptana/

Comment: So basically, let's forget Dreamweaver, and try Aptana??? let's see how that works, tried creating the app in Appinventor... the basic app is a success, but the file is 1.5 Mb... let's see if Aptana makes it any easier

Comment: actually you can use dreamweaver (i did)

Comment: Of course you can use Dreamweaver to write the javascript code for Appcelerator. It's the WYSIWYG part that won't do anything, as you won't be writing HTML. It's because of this that Dreamweaver is not a handy solution.