# what is the internal procedure by which .apk file is formed in titanium framework?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I m writing javascript code in titanium Ide. When i run the code .apk file is formed which i can install in the android device.I want to know the internal process how the .apk file is formed from javascript code in titanium? I want to know the whole thing step by  step. Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been documented on SO already. Check this post:
[What happens to JavaScript code after app is compiled using Titanium Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217551/what-happens-to-javascript-code-after-app-is-compiled-using-titanium-mobile)

By the time the APK is created your using the exact same toolchain that you would use natively, Titanium just does it for you.