# Titanium: How apk is build with Titanium studio

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I am trying to create an APK manually with the Titanium Source.. I searched and found that Titanium is using ANT tool to build the APK..So i gave "ant" command in terminal it created an APK but it misses some folders named org and ti.. Which are used in Intializing Webview at Runtime.. So Plz guide me how to compile the source manually **(Using commands in terminal/Command Prompt i.e "Ant" commands like aapt, dex etc)..**

I gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217551/what-happens-to-javascript-code-after-app-is-compiled-using-titanium-mobile) but it just has overview of it, but not the full flow..

Thanks in Advance

Regards,

Deepak

Comment: Deepak, I couldn't understand what you've meant by 'manually'. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I had edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the Titanium Command line Interface. https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Titanium+Command+Line+Interface

```
$ titanium create --platform=android --android=/path/to/android-sdk --id=com.mycompany.myApp --name=myApp   
$ titanium run --platform=android
```

If you are going with 3.0 SDK, then you can use npm to install `and` manage your dependencies and execute the same Titanium commands or you can use `Alloy` if you are with their new architecture.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/10/building-titanium-mobile-from-source-now-requires-nodejs.html