# titanium - how can i tell that the compilejs command worked?

Tags: javascript, titanium

I have some titanium code. Currently, it runs irritatingly slowly on my sample device when animating a simple ball dropping down the side.

(The drop down checks every millisecond or so to see if a key has been pressed - which ends up making the ball "stagger" down instead of smoothly dropping).
*
I'm unsure if this is my code, or the fact that titanium on android precompiles to some stuff and then some more java stuff. I'm sketchy on the details - but they can be found here, if curious:

[What happens to JavaScript code after app is compiled using Titanium Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217551/what-happens-to-javascript-code-after-app-is-compiled-using-titanium-mobile?lq=1)

Anyway, i've turned on the "copile to java please" flag like so (in the tiapp.xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <property name="ti.android.compilejs" type="bool">true</property>
    ... all the other stuff here.
```

Questions!

1. But now when i look at the info displayed when i send the app to my mobile phone, it still pushed an apk file... is it meant to? I would have thought a .java or .jar? Or do i not get mobile development?
2. The app itself doesn't seem any faster - or slower. The animation still staggers. Shouldn't i expect a speed up when running the java code directly?
3. The app itself isn't any smaller in size. Should i expect it to be?
4. The time to publish the app to the phone is not slower - i thought it would be?

Based on the above, does it sound like i've got the titanium running from .java code? Or is it still doing the annoying-developer-mode stuff?

Comment: Could you show some code? This is likely just how you are handling your events that make the animation stagger.

Comment: fair enough - i asked the core question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272610/titanium-animation-is-v-v-choppy