# Animation jerks in android device in titanium

Tags: android, animation, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have explore almost anything but couldn't find anything convincing which can verify that why animation jerks if try to animate any window through its `animate` property.

And this jerk occurs only on android part, in IOS it works perfectly even in lower devices. But why does it jerk in android? Your inputs are welcome on this.

What I've found so far is that, it might happen because of **heavyweight** and **lightweight** window concept but as in **Titanium 3.2.0** there is only **heavyweight** window and still it jerks.

Even if we adjust our animation time but still animation is not smooth and as we increase the time animation will jerks more. But decreasing animation time is not a solution as in this case animation is jerking but apparently not caught. So please give your inputs on this for future correspondence.

Thank You

Comment: There are a ton of things that could be causing this. I haven't messed with iOS but Android and Titanium has always been a bit sluggish for me (even with simple drop down animations). Have you tried creating a transitional 2d matrix? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272610/titanium-animation-is-v-v-choppy

Comment: And what version of Android are you running this on? Device or emulator?

Comment: @zgc7009 I just want want slider menu animation and I'll b happy to know about rest of the animation to work smoothly..

Comment: @DawsonToth I was runnning it on Galaxy S4.. version 4.2

Comment: @zgc7009 I have used all the transformation and even for loop but nothing giving me smooth experience..

Answer (score 0):

The following native module increases performance: 
https://github.com/animecyc/TitaniumAnimator

Other things that cause animations to perform poorly (Android only):

- Rounded corners on views (this prevents hardware acceleration). So use 9 patch images or image masks when you want to animate rounded child views in the parent view you animate.
- Background images on the view you'r animating drastically decrease performance. Especially large view backgrounds. A pattern backgroundImage tile.png with a view attribute backgroundRepeat=true help to improve performance.

Unfortunately taking the above into account when trying what elements to animate, Android is still very much behind iOS.