# Integrating platform-specific API's in multiplatform mobile app (Flex / Titanium)

Tags: apache-flex, api, titanium, multiplatform, mobile-application

My team is in the planning phase of a multiplatform mobile app. We're considering Adobe Air/Flex or Appcelerator Titanium instead of native development, but will eventually be needing to use an external API that is ported to iOS and Android. **(one that harnesses the device's camera)

The idea would be to use platform detection and overloaded classes to determine which platform version of the API to import. Is something like this possible in either Adobe or Appcelerator? If so, would the native Objective-C or Java need to somehow be wrapped in Actionscript (if Adobe) or JavaScript (if Titanium)?

Any advice would be fantastic.

Comment: can you expand more on your requirements?  What do you mean 'one that harnesses the device's camera'?

Comment: Thanks. A later release will need access to the pixel stream from the camera (much like AVFoundation in native iOS) or allow for the incorporation of the RedLaser API.

Comment: Yeah, Air for Mobile doesn't have the capability to access the pixel stream just yet.

Comment: Where would I find out what's in their to-do queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A near-term (no dates yet) release of Mobile Air will include native extensions.  The native code will be written in the platforms' native languages.  ActionScript interfaces will exist to interact with these extensions, the specifications for which have not yet been released.

http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/news/industry-news-week-22-2011/

Answer (score 1):

Titanium is 100% native code.

[How Does Appcelerator Titanium Mobile Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work/2471774#2471774)