# how to create simple application in titanium studio using ruby code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, titanium

I installed titanium studio (in windows 7) to create a android mobile application using ruby. But i don't know how to start a simple application using ruby code.

Anyone can helps me to create simple application using ruby.

Comment: I don't think you understand how Titanium works, read about it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work

Answer (score 0):

Ruby support is only available (and at that, only partially) in Titanium desktop apps - there's no Ruby support for mobile applications right now.

All coding in Titanium mobile is done using javascript, which as you can imagine, has certain upsides and downsides.  For example, to make my apps, I had to implement a class system on top of the class-less javascript language, build an ActiveRecord-like database abstraction layer over the sqlite database, etc. to get to the type of facilities I'm used to using in my Ruby/Rails projects.  But it's all still in javascript.

That said, javascript is quite Ruby-like in many ways, and is much preferable (to me at least) than using either Java syntax or Objective C syntax for coding, even with the basic support provided.  But if you don't have a mastery of javascript (in particular closures and functional scoping) you will need to read up to use Titanium.