# Does and how does Titanium convert css to native?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I read the explanation here about how titanium convert js to native - though there is an interpreter for dynamic parts:

[How Does Appcelerator Titanium Mobile Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work/2471774#2471774)

What about CSS ? I can't see how css could be mapped in native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last Titanium SDK doesn't support CSS. You can use css in WebView, but not for other components.

As alternative - create module and add all your styles to it. Then include this module to any js file and use it's styles. You can read about modules [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium).