# Is Titanium appcelarator an interpreted application?

Tags: appcelerator

Is the appcelerator applications interpreted at run time ? Does it has an interpreter on the mobile device to do so ?

Please share any informative links on the same.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work/2471774#2471774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, the JavaScript code is interpreted on runtime. That's why it depends on Rhino/V8 for Android, for example.

It was also mentioned on part of a [talk](http://player.vimeo.com/video/30391192?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=9a0707&autoplay=1) during [CODESTRONG 2011](http://www.appcelerator.com/showcase/videos/codestrong2011/).

You can always read more about [How Appcelerator Works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work/2471774#2471774)