# Can I convert to Swift in Titanium?

Tags: node.js, swift, titanium, titanium-studio

I'm building an app in Titanium in node.js. For my targets I have Android and iOS but I want my iOS target to output native iOS in Swift and **not** in objective-c.

How can I do this? Is this possible at all?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium used Node.js for the compiler, you wouldn't use much node in your actual app. Also Titanium compiles to a native format but it doesn't literally convert your code in to objective-c / Java and then compile that, at least not directly. The best explanation I've seen is [How Does Appcelerator Titanium Mobile Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444001/how-does-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work/2471774#2471774)

So no, there is no way for this to convert to Swift and if you're looking for a Javascript->Swift converter I cannot imagine it exists. Maybe if you let me know what you are actually trying to achieve, I may be able to help further.